# Windows Azure Cache - Naming Convention

Tags: windows, caching, azure

So I ran into a very strange issue.  When trying to create a new Cache within Azure, I could not use the string '3web' within the name.  Every combination returned the error, "The name you chose is already being used."  I found this highly unlikely, as I even tried the following name:

asdasdaqqdasd3webzyx.cache.windows.net and it stated it was already in use.  If I type my name, or something else, everything works great, however, something is throwing up when i utilize '3web' anywhere in the name.

Answer (score 0):

There are rules in place for names when they result in a public facing URI.  Each name is run through a routine and either rejected or accepted based on the name alone.  They are also tested to see if they already existed as well.  In your case it's definitely unlikely that the longer name you provided existed and it was rejected for some other reason, though if that is the case it's a horrible error message.  I've recently seen others complain about the same issue when they had a name rejected that was basically a random set of characters.  It is very unclear as to what algorithm is being used for acceptable names and if all of the services share the same name checking routines.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Looks like there might be an issue with Cache right now, as I can't create any caches (even with valid names).  Oh well, I guess that is why it is in preview.